# Using boolean values for <option> values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I store "isAvailable" prop as boolean, but when handleChange function runs it turns my boolean variable into string. Is it possible to keep "isAvailable" boolean without creating another function for handling changes?

Here is my rendered selectbox :

```
<select
    type='text'
    name="isAvailable"
    className='itemAvailability form__input'
    value={this.props.details.isAvailable}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
>
    <option>Availability</option>
    <option value={true}>Available</option>
    <option value={false}>Not Available</option>
</select>
```

And here is handleChange function

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    const updatedItem = {
        ...this.props.details,
        [e.currentTarget.name]: e.currentTarget.value
    }

    this.props.updateItem(this.props.index, updatedItem);
}
```

Comment: Random note: if there are exactly two options consider using a `<input type='radio'` rather than a `<select` which would give you this sort of functionality for free.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks for the advice Benjamin, the field needs to remain as selectbox to fit the design.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution for those having the same problem. I've updated my handleChange function as shown below.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    let updatedValue = e.currentTarget.value;

    if (updatedValue === "true" || updatedValue == "false") {
        updatedValue = JSON.parse(updatedValue);
    }

    const updatedItem = {
        ...this.props.details,
        [e.currentTarget.name]: updatedValue
    }

    this.props.updateItem(this.props.index, updatedItem);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The value property of an HTML `option` element can only be a string. If you want to get boolean values, you should probably setup a [radio input field](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Late, but I figured I would show how I handle something similar to this. Once my option hits the mongo db the value is set as a boolean, but before the page is refreshed redux stores the option as a string, so added a check for the string to show the change in the meantime.

```
onChangeHandler = (event) => {
    this.props.userInfoUpdate(
        event.target.name, event.target.value
    )
}



        const display_address = () => {
        if(!this.props.display_address || this.props.display_address === 'true'){
            return (
                <select name='display_address' onChange={this.onChangeHandler} >
                    <option value={true}>Yes</option>
                    <option value={false}>No</option>                    
                </select>
            )
        }else{
            return (
                <select name='display_address' onChange={this.onChangeHandler} >
                    <option value={false}>No</option>
                    <option value={true}>Yes</option>                                            
                </select>
            )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[2023] There is a work around where you can check for the current selected value and return a final value based off that.

Eg: For your code above

```
<select
    type='text'
    name="isAvailable"
    className='itemAvailability form__input'
    value={this.props.details.isAvailable}
    onChange={this.handleChange}
>
    <option>Availability</option>
    <option value={true}>Available</option>
    <option value={false}>Not Available</option>
</select>
```

---

In your data to be submitted, you can have:

```
const dataToSubmit= {
    isAvailable:
      formdata.isAvailable === "true"
        ? true`enter code here`
        : formdata.isAvailable === "false"
        ? false
        : null,
  };
```